# How to extract lines by words in specific position, not column?

Tags: bash, text-processing, columns, text

I have an input file like this:

```
                     v
ATOM     57  O   LYS A   7       2.254  25.484  18.942  1.00 14.46
ATOM     77  NH1AARG A   8       5.557  19.204  13.388  0.55 24.50
TER    1648      ILE C 206
HETATM 1668  O   HOH A1023      25.873  38.343   2.138  1.00 21.99
                     ^
```

Only lines contains `A` at the marked position are what I need. In most lines, `A` is a single character as a fifth column like the first line. However, sometimes it's on the fourth column like the second row, or in a string like the last one. Note that `A` as a single character can appear in positions other than 22, but I only care when it's here.

I need my output to have only lines with `A`, regardless it is in single or in string:

```
ATOM     57  O   LYS A   7       2.254  25.484  18.942  1.00 14.46
ATOM     77  NH1AARG A   8       5.557  19.204  13.388  0.55 24.50
HETATM 1668  O   HOH A1023      25.873  38.343   2.138  1.00 21.99
```

But sometimes I also want to extract only lines with single `A`, regardless its column:

```
ATOM     57  O   LYS A   7       2.254  25.484  18.942  1.00 14.46
ATOM     77  NH1AARG A   8       5.557  19.204  13.388  0.55 24.50
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -E '^.{21}A' file
```

if you want to include cases like `A1023`, and

```
grep -E '^.{21}A\>' file
```

if you want only lines where `A` appears as an isolated character

**NOTE:** In the second example the notation <kbd>\></kbd> will match any trailing empty strings.

*excerpt from grep man page*

> #### The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
>
> The  symbols  `\<` and `\>` respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.  The symbol `\b` matches the empty string at
>   the edge of a word, and `\B` matches the empty string provided it's not at the edge of a word.  The symbol `\w` is a synonym  for  `[_[:alnum:]]`
>   and `\W` is a synonym for `[^_[:alnum:]]`.

Answer (score 6):

bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    [[ ${line:21:2} == "A " ]] && echo "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: One of our master users just announced that he downvotes all bash read loops... ;-)

Comment: Upvoted on principle :)

Answer (score 3):

```
> awk -v FS= '{ print $22 }' file
A
A
C
A

> awk -v FS= '$22=="A" { print; }' file
ATOM     57  O   LYS A   7       2.254  25.484  18.942  1.00 14.46
ATOM     77  NH1AARG A   8       5.557  19.204  13.388  0.55 24.50
HETATM 1668  O   HOH A1023      25.873  38.343   2.138  1.00 21.99
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. What if I only want to extract A, not Aabce?

Comment: @Ooker I really don't understand the question as you can clearly see in the example that only "A" is "extracted"... Furthermore I have no idea what "Aabce" refers to.

Comment: Aabce is A1023 in the example. Say I want to extract only ` A ` in the 22nd position. There are others ` A ` in other places, but I don't want them.

Comment: @Ooker I don't get your problem. You probably have to provide an example input line and tell me what my code does wrong with it i.e. what you expect instead.

Comment: sorry if I don't make it clear. I have edited my question, please come and see.

Comment: @Ooker Is that a very strange way of saying that you want to match "A" only if it is followed by a space?

Comment: I don't know, maybe.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - could you explain how this works? I see that it does but do not understand the `FS= '$22=="A"..` bit.

Comment: @slm Wow... That's not obvious, you just have to know it: "If FS is the null string, then each individual character becomes a separate field."

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I've been learning `awk`, it's not my first language but have been trying to wrap my head around many of the examples here. So when you say `FS= ` that implies the NULL string? Also when I change the `'$22=="A"` to `'$22="A"` I see all the characters are split when I run it that way, is that what you mean by each character becoming a separate field?

Comment: @slm I just remembered that statement from the man page. `FS=` was the second try (`-F ` doesn't work). `$22="A"` means that you assign a value to `$22`, not that you check its value. Assigning a value leads to `$0` being recomputed - with `OFS` between each two fields.

Answer (score 3):

One point I've noticed about the data you describe is that your A - regardless of its column position - is the *last* alphabetic character on the line. That means we can address it systematically like this:

```
sed -n '\|.*\(A\)[ 0-9.]*$|s||\1|p'
```

That returns only the `A`, but if you want the whole line just change the `\1` to an `&`.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU grep`:

```
$ grep -P '\bA\b' file
ATOM     57  O   LYS A   7       2.254  25.484  18.942  1.00 14.46
ATOM     77  NH1AARG A   8       5.557  19.204  13.388  0.55 24.50
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk command irrespective of position of A,

```
$ awk '$4~/A$/ || $5~/^A/' file
ATOM     57  O   LYS A   7       2.254  25.484  18.942  1.00 14.46
ATOM     77  NH1AARG A   8       5.557  19.204  13.388  0.55 24.50
HETATM 1668  O   HOH A1023      25.873  38.343   2.138  1.00 21.99
```

And the lines which consists of `space A space`,

```
$ awk '/ A /' file
ATOM     57  O   LYS A   7       2.254  25.484  18.942  1.00 14.46
ATOM     77  NH1AARG A   8       5.557  19.204  13.388  0.55 24.50
```